# golang overflow int64 with operating directly but not with assigned a value beforehand?

Tags: go, overflow, int64

```
func main() {
   var a = math.MaxInt64
   fmt.Println(a + 1)             //-9223372036854775808
   fmt.Println(math.MaxInt64 + 1) //constant 9223372036854775808 overflows int
}

why the two ways perform differently?
```

Comment: have your run your program it is giving error for both as overflow

Comment: The one is a constant the other a variable. One is evaluated at compile time, the other at runtime. Read about constants in Go in the Blog.

Answer (score 4):

In the second example `math.MaxInt64 + 1` is a constant expression and is computed at compile time. The [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions) says:

> Constant expressions are always evaluated exactly; intermediate values and the constants themselves may require precision significantly larger than supported by any predeclared type in the language.

However when the value of the expression is passed to `fmt.Println` it has to be converted into a real predeclared type, in this case an `int`, which is represented as a signed 64 bit integer, which is incapable of representing the constant.

> A constant may be given a type explicitly by a constant declaration or conversion, or implicitly when used in a variable declaration or an assignment or as an operand in an expression. It is an error if the constant value cannot be represented as a value of the respective type.

In the first example `a + 1` is not a constant expression, rather it's normal arithmetic because `a` was declared to be a variable and so the constant expression `math.MaxInt64` is converted to an `int`. It's the same as:

```
var a int = math.MaxInt64
```

Normal arithmetic is allowed to overflow:

> For signed integers, the operations +, -, *, /, and << may legally overflow and the resulting value exists and is deterministically defined by the signed integer representation, the operation, and its operands. No exception is raised as a result of overflow.

With minor modifications you can make the examples the same:

```
func main() {
    const a = math.MaxInt64
    fmt.Println(a + 1)             //constant 9223372036854775808 overflows int
    fmt.Println(math.MaxInt64 + 1) //constant 9223372036854775808 overflows int
}
```

Comment: Great answer @caleb! Well explained and referenced. I've learned something.

Answer (score 1):

It is showing an error because if you check the type of a constant value of `1` it will show you that you are actually adding `int` to a `int64` value. So first declare a variable of type int64 and than add to `const math.MaxInt64` just like that

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
   var a int64 = 1 
   fmt.Println(math.MaxInt64 + a)             //-9223372036854775808
   fmt.Printf("%#T", 1)
   //fmt.Println(math.MaxInt64 + 1) //constant 9223372036854775808 overflows 
}
```